# A customer model to a order model that has price values in Django

Tags: python, django, models

I was trying to build a restaurant management app using Django, my Customer model has a name, orders, a table integer field and an is_active boolean field. I have a working form up that creates a Customer obj and assigns it its orders separated by commas, which I then render using a model method.

What  I want to do is have multiple order fields in a Customer field and then a certain order field should be linked directly to a fixed price.

I'm quite new to Django, so here's how I can explain it best: when you create a customer object, you should see a Name field, multiple order fields which should also have some quantity fields which should both then be linked to a fixed price because I will use that to calculate a total price: fixed_price_of_order multiplied by the quantity_ordered.

I have tried to find something similar, but I haven't really been able to yet. Django might not be the best tool for this, but this is what I have to use.

**EDIT**
Here's what I have today, got a bit further than yesterday, aka I can type in the orders manually, but that's error prone and not exactly fun to use.

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0, unique=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=120, unique=True)
    order = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
    table = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now what I need is a way to track quantities, I thought about adding a quantity field to Item, but that wouldn't work because not every order has the same quantity of Item. I looked it up and saw some stuff about a through table, couldn't understand what that is or any way to use it. I can live with the manual field entering for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you need 3 tables,
Customer, for the details of a specific customer,
Item, for a specific item,
Order, for every order each customer makes.

Here's an example:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = ...........
    price = ..........

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = .........
    ..........

class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, related_name='orders', null=True, blank=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='orders', null=True, blank=True)
    order_date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    is_cancelled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

By doing like this, you can have a single customer with multiple orders related to single or multiple items. The quantity field can be added to the Order table, so that each order can have its own quantity.

This is just what I thought how it can be, Hope you got what you were looking for.

Comment: This works perfectly, had to move a few things around but thanks a lot. I was thinking of doing something like this but couldn't figure out how to implement it. Learned something new!

Comment: If you are satisfied, then can you do me a favor and tag the answer as selected?

Comment: Appreciate the support.. Glad I could be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read about django [Widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/) and then use [SelectMultiple](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/widgets/#selectmultiple) widget.

Btw. Please, paste your code. It would be much easier to help.

Comment: I'm unable to post my code because I'm lying in bed questioning existence right now. I will update my this with my code tomorrow. Thanks a lot though, this seems like it would work!

Comment: Updated with the code and progress, still not quite there though >.<