# How to add more than one food item per order with Django Models?

Tags: django, django-models

I am building an App for my brother's Bar. He will take orders and charge.  I have a 'Food' and a 'Order' model. Let's say:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    Stock = models.BooleanField()

class Order(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    Product = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    Quantity = models.IntegerField()

    TotalPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
```

I cannot figure out how to add, on the same order, more than one food. Also specify quantity for each food.

Comment: I think I am looking something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810254/a-customer-model-to-a-order-model-that-has-price-values-in-django/

But I am not sure how the "related_name" will help me. And how to implement it .

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 1):

Your models aren't right here. You need *three* models: Order, Food, and OrderItem, which is a list of food items for each order. So:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    ...

class Order(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    TotalPrice = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    Order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    Product = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    Quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

Now given an instance of Order, you would get the items by doing `my_order.orderitem_set.all()`.

(Note, usual Python style is to have lower_case names for attributes like fields: `total_price`, `product`, `quantity`.)

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes. I think this is what I am looking for. I will try to implement this and let you know. Thanks!!